# How to Add/Remove Items from NSCollectionView with Multiple Sections

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

**Background:**
I'm a new developer, and I'm not sure where to go to get help. I've been troubleshooting this issue for the past week, but I don't know what is causing the problem. This is my first post, and I want to be a good member, so please let me know if I've made any mistakes and I'll gladly correct them.

Thank you!

**Problem:**
I'm setting up a `NSCollectionView` that has 5 sections. There are 5 buttons that add new items into the five sections, and there is one button that removes selected items. Currently, there is one button set up.

But, the items do not seem to add or remove properly in the collection view.

And, the app crashes if there are not items added to the collection view at launch.

Also, when adding new items, it adds an extra item to the collection view.

**Work:** 
I've worked through several `NSCollectionView` tutorials, such raywenderlich.com, ductran.com, youtube videos, medium articles, stackoverflow.com posts, and apple documentation.

Here are a few of the links that were more helpful:
[raywenderlich - part 1](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1246-collection-views-in-os-x-tutorial)
[raywenderlich - part 2](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1047-advanced-collection-views-in-os-x-tutorial)
[ductran - photo app](https://www.ductran.co/blog/uicollectionview-in-ios-with-swift-tutorial)
[ductran - news app](https://github.com/amglobal99/CollectionViews_DucTran) 
[apple - documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/views_and_controls/collection_view)

I've debugged line by line from beginning to end, started from scratch a couple times, built the simplest collection view and added to it step by step, referenced from UICollectionView.

I'm eager to learn, but the resources available on `NSCollectionView` seem slim.

**Code:** 
I'm not sure where the problem is, so I don't know which code to post.

I've uploaded the app to github: [Link](https://github.com/captaindavepdx/mac-os-app/tree/e3c67f915dbd00c7154be37f3f0a1986b029d328)

I think the problem could be occurring at `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths`. The wrong item gets deleted, and the app crashes if all the items are deleted:

```
func deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(_ indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        var indexes = [Int]()
        for indexPath in indexPaths {
            indexes.append(absoluteIndexForIndexPath(indexPath))
        }
        var newWebsites = [Website]()
        for (index, website) in websites.enumerated() {
            if !indexes.contains(index) {
                newWebsites.append(website)
            }
        }
        websites = newWebsites
    }

fileprivate func absoluteIndexForIndexPath(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int {
    var index = 0
    for i in 0 ... (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section {
        index += numberOfWebsitesInSection(i)
    }
    index += (indexPath as NSIndexPath).item
    return index
}
```

Comment: A few suggestions for improving the question, to hopefully help you get better answers, and/or more quickly: 1. learn and use more of the formatting tools, e.g. especially use backticks to write things like NSCollectionView as `NSCollectionView` – this helps make the question easier to visually scan for salient bits of information 2. if possible, link to the specific tutorials and documents you were looking at; 3. regarding code, it's nice to have the whole repo, but maybe make a guess at which code is relevant, and post some of it.  Also, link to a specific commit, in case you fix it later.

Comment: Regarding the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionview), did you see [the `allowsEmptySelection` flag](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionview/1528180-allowsemptyselection)?  I'm not familiar enough with `NSCollectionView` stuff to know if that's relevant, I just observe that it seems possibly-apropos of "the app crashes if there are not items added to the collection view at launch"... maybe.

Comment: @lindes, I've added your suggestions - it does look much better, thank you!

Comment: @lindes Also, `allowsEmptySelection` relates to selecting/highlighting items in the collection view. If `false`, an item is always selected. If `true`, no items can be selected.

Comment: @lindes, I figured it out! Writing out the problem, and talking about it with you, helped clarify the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidLittlefield Please do _not_ add "solved" to your question's title! Stackoverflow is not a forum. When you finish writing up your solution, post is as an _answer_, them _mark_ that answer as the solution to your problem. Read [faq] and [ask].

Comment: @dandan78, I've followed your suggestions, thank you! Also, stackoverflow.com stated I had to wait two days to select my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Adding/Deleting:**
The extra/wrong item was related to `absoluteIndexForIndexPath`. It was set to ... instead of ..< 
**Crashing:** 
The crash was related to `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`. The `NSCollectionView` function needed an `if/then` set for `websitesInSection > 0`
Working `NSCollectionView` with 5 Sections and 5 Buttons: [Link](https://github.com/captaindavepdx/mac-os-app/tree/10b0c4466b46d272d18cdc55eacc7757fa5d2588)